# Behaviour of Join-Path cmdlet between Powershell v4 and v5

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I'm executing the following command on a machine where `G:` drive does not exist:

```
Join-Path "G:\" "abc.txt"
```

In Powershell v5, this returns "G:\abc.txt" as expected. I simply want to join sub-paths and not validate it's existence.
On the other hand, in Powershell v4, it fails with the following error:

```
Join-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'G' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Join-Path "G:\" "abc.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (G:String) [Join-Path], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

For some reasons I am stuck with using Powershell v4 and cannot make a move to Powershell v5 right now. Is there any out-of-the-box solution for simply joining sub-paths in Powershell v4 or do I need to create a custom solution?

Comment: It is the same behavior in v5. If drive not exist, it produce error.

Comment: Ahh you're right! Stupid mistake on my part. I was testing with Powershell v5 on a machine which actually had `G:` drive. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. It's by design ( I've not tested it on version 5.0)

You need to concat strings and eventually cast to `[System.IO.fileinfo]`:

```
$a = 'G:\'
$b = 'abc.txt'
$mypath = [system.io.fileinfo]($a.TrimEnd('\') + '\' +  $b.TrimStart('\'))
```

[Link on microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/779068/join-path-and-split-path-should-not-fail-if-the-path-does-not-exist-on-the-current-machine)

from `get-help join-path -full`:

```
The Join-Path cmdlet is designed to work with the data exposed by any provider. To list the providers
available in your session, type "Get-PSProvider". For more information, see about_Providers.
```

Comment: This solution can be made more robust as follows:
`$mypath = [system.io.fileinfo]($a.TrimEnd('\', '/') + '\' + $b.TrimStart('\', '/'))`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the exists check, you can use [`Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.Path]::Combine('G:\','nonexistingfile.txt')
G:\nonexistingfile.txt
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: in case of `[System.IO.Path]::Combine('G:','nonexistingfile.txt')` the result is `g:nonexistingfile.txt`. Is a different behavior from what `join-path` do.